# Open Modal Into Subscribe Service

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

is there any way to open a modal within a resolver for a service? now it gives me error.

```
RegistroComponent.html:98 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
```

this is the code.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

import { TipoEquipoService } from '../../tipo-equipo/tipo-equipo.service';
import { MarcaService } from '../../marca/marca.service';
import { RangoService } from '../../rango/rango.service';
import { EmpleadoService } from '../../shared/services/empleado.service';
import { EquipoService } from './../equipo.service';
import { ResponsableService } from '../../shared/services/responsable.service';

// Models
import { Equipo } from './../equipo';
import { TipoEquipo } from '../../tipo-equipo/tipo-equipo';
import { Marca } from '../../marca/marca';
import { Rango } from '../../rango/rango';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';
import { ConfirmComponent } from '../../shared/components/confirm/confirm.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registro',
  templateUrl: './registro.component.html',
  providers: [],
  styleUrls: ['./registro.component.css']
})

export class RegistroComponent implements OnInit {

  tiposEquipo: TipoEquipo[] = [];
  marcas: Marca[] = [];
  rangos: Rango[] = [];
  equipo: Equipo = new Equipo(0, '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', '', '', 1, '', new Date(), '', new Date());
  searching = false;
  searchFailed = false;
  nombreEmp: string;
  IdResponsable = {};
  closeResult: string;

  constructor(private tipEquiSrv: TipoEquipoService,
    private marcaSrv: MarcaService,
    private rangoSrv: RangoService,
    private empleadoSrv: EmpleadoService,
    private equipoSrv: EquipoService,
    private responsableSrv: ResponsableService,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    public toastr: ToastsManager, vcr: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(vcr);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tipEquiSrv.getTipoEquipo().subscribe(tipos => { this.tiposEquipo = tipos; });
    this.marcaSrv.getMarcas().subscribe(marcas => this.marcas = marcas);
    this.rangoSrv.getRangos().subscribe(rangos => { this.rangos = rangos; });
  }

  registro() {
    console.log(this.equipo);
    // this.equipoSrv.addEquipo(this.equipo)
    //   .subscribe(
    //   data => console.log(data),
    //   err => console.log(err),
    //   () => console.log('Request Completa')
    //   );
  }

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .do(() => this.searching = true)
      .switchMap(term =>
        this.empleadoSrv.getEmpleadoLike(term)
          .do(() => this.searchFailed = false)
          .catch(() => {
            this.searchFailed = true;
            return Observable.of([]);
          }))
      .do(() => this.searching = false)

  // formatter = (x: { nombre: string }) => x.nombre;

  inputFormatter(x) {
    return x.empleadoId;
  }

  resultFormatter(x) {
    return x.nombre;
  }

  onBlurMethod() {
    // Consulto la Cedula en Responsables
    this.responsableSrv.getResponsableCed(this.IdResponsable['empleadoId'])
      .subscribe(responsable => {
        console.log(responsable);
        if (responsable == null) {
          const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmComponent);
          // const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmComponent);
          // modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'El Responsable no Existe, Desea Crearlo?';
          // modalRef.componentInstance.titulo = 'Alerta!';
          // modalRef.result.then((result) => {
          //   console.log('result');
          //   console.log(result);
          // }, (reason) => {
          //   console.log('reason');
          //   console.log(reason);
          // });
        }
      });

  }

  public onSelectTypeahead(eventItem) {
    this.nombreEmp = eventItem.nombre;
  }
}
```

Thank you very much for your collaboration, I have not been able to solve it for several hours, I am new to angular, I have asked in other forums but they have not given me an answer.

Comment: Can you include the whole class?

Comment: @getbuckts Of course, I already updated the post.

Comment: Unless I debug this with your code, its going to be hard to tell.  From my own experience this error happens when you have a binding and in your template, your updating that same variable somehow.

Comment: @getbuckts Occurs in the "onBlurMethod" method. When I open the mode, the error will be skipped. I can not know what happens, I just know it has to do with the "subscribe".

Comment: I would take a step wise approach..1.  Onblur output something to console.  2.  make your service call and in the subscription output something.  If those 2 things work something ups with your ConfirmComponent.  If 2 fails that means your service call is updating something that angular is trying to refresh but has detected that value has changed before it could finish.  Again this usually has to do with binding.

Comment: @getbuckts It is just what you indicate, but I do not know how to solve it. It occurs to me, I will make a variable S or N according to the case and in onblur valid so to avoid the problem with the service. I think it's the easiest solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ideally your service should not modify model data in your controller.  Just have a subscription should not cause that error, sometihng is updating some data and agular is like, whoa....I'm in the process of updating views and you just updated the data while I'm updating...no bueno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line

```
this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.elRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.activeElement, 'blur');
```

before your

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmComponent);
```

Don't forget add to constructor

```
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {}
```

So it should be something like this

```
//***Your code ***
constructor(private tipEquiSrv: TipoEquipoService,
    private marcaSrv: MarcaService,
    private rangoSrv: RangoService,
    private empleadoSrv: EmpleadoService,
    private equipoSrv: EquipoService,
    private responsableSrv: ResponsableService,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    public toastr: ToastsManager, vcr: ViewContainerRef,
    private elRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer
) {
    this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(vcr);
  }
//***Your code***
if (responsable == null) {
this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.elRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.activeElement, 'blur');
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmComponent);
//***Your code***
```

The problem with focusing inputs when modal opening. I had the same problem. Only this line with unfocused helped me.
You can read more [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) about this problem.